# Is using a read only root file system a good idea for embedded setup?

Tags: embedded, ram, readonly, root-filesystem, buildroot

I have been tasked with running Linux as an operating system on an embedded device.

The target has an x86 processor and has 8 GB CompactFlash device for storage.

I have managed to use buildroot to create the kernel image and cross compilation tools. I have partitioned the CF device into a small FAT partition where the kernel image resides as well as `syslinux` boot configuration and an `ext3` file system where I have decompressed the root file system generated by buildroot to.

The system boots successfully using `syslinux` by setting the root directory to the CF ext3 partition where my buildroot file system is located.

My question is centred around the need for robustness in the face of immediate (and frequent) power loss as it is crucial for the device to boot successfully after power outages. I have read that mounting the root file system as read only is a way of ensuring data integrity. Is this a sensible way for me to proceed?

I have also read about the possibility of loading the root file system into RAM to achieve the same thing but as yet do not know how to do so.

Is there a preferred way of achieving this goal and if so what is the best way for me to proceed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### New answer (2015-03-22)

(**Note:** This answer is simpler than previous, but not more secure. My first answer is stronger because you could keep files *read-only* by *fs mount options* **before** permission flags. So *forcing* to write a files without permission to write won't work at all.)

Yes, under [Debian](http://debian.org), there is a package: [fsprotect](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/fsprotect) ([homepage](https://www.v13.gr/index.php?nocache=0&m=cms&s=&site=vsite&viewid=5&bcontentprojid=1)).

It use `aufs` (by default, but could use another `unionfs` tool) to permit *live session changes* but in RAM by default, so everything is forgotten at reboot.

You could install them by running simply:

```
apt-get install fsprotect
```

Once done, from online doc:

> After that:
>
> - Edit `/boot/grub/menu.lst` or `/etc/default/grub2` or `/etc/lilo.conf` and add "`fsprotect=1G`" to kernel parameters.
> - Modify 1G as needed.
> - Apply changes (i.e. run `update-grub`)
> - Edit `/etc/default/fsprotect` if you want to protect filesystems other than `/`.
> - reboot
>
> You may also want to password protect the grub bootloader or forbid any changes to it.

From there, if some file is protected against changes, for sample by

```
chmod ugo-w myfile
```

if you use for sample `vi myfile` and try to write on it with command `:w!`, this will work and your  `myfile` became changed. You may reboot in order to retrieve unmodified `myfile`.

That's not even possible with my following first solution:

### Old (first) answer:

Yes, it is a strong solution, but powerfull!

#### Making r/o useable

You have to mount some directories in *rw*, like `/var`, `/etc` and maybe `/home`. This could by done using *aufs* or *unionfs*. I like this *another way*, using `/dev/shm` and `mount --bind`:

```
cp -a /var /dev/shm/
mount --bind /dev/shm/var /var
```

You could before, move all directories who have not to change in normal operation in a `static-var`, than create symlinks in /var:

```
mkdir /static-var
mkdir /static-var/cache
mkdir /static-var/lib
mv /var/lib/dpkg /static-var/lib/dpkg
ln -s /static-var/lib/dpkg /var/lib/dpkg
mv /var/cache/apt /static-var/cache/apt
ln -s /static-var/cache/apt /var/cache/apt
... # an so on
```

So when remounting in ro, copying `/var` in `/dev/shm` won't take too much space as most files are moved to `/static-var` and only symlinks are to be copied in ram.

The better way to do this finely is to make a full power-cycle, one day of full work and finely run a command like:

```
find / -type f -o -type f -mtime -1
```

So you will see which files needs to be located on read-write partition.

#### Logging

As in this host no writeable static memory exist, in order to store history and other logs, you have to config a remote `syslog` server.

```
echo >/etc/syslog.conf '*.* @mySyslogServer.localdomain'
```

In this way, if your system break for any reason, everything before is logged.

#### Upgrading

When running whith some `mount --bind` in use, for doing such an upgrade while system is in use (whithout the need of running `init 1`, for reducing down-time), the simplier way is to re-build a clean *root*, able to do the upgrade:

After remounting '/' in *read-write* mode:

```
mount -o remount,rw /

for mpnt in /{,proc,sys,dev{,/pts}};do
    mount --bind $mnpt /$mnt$mpnt;
    done

chroot /mnt

apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade

exit

umount /mnt/{dev{/pts,},proc,sys,}

sync
mount -o remount,ro /
```

And now:

```
shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not completely understand it as my Linux skills are not great at the moment. It is still very helpful though and gives me some more areas to research.

Comment: Answer edited! New solution and explained diffs!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it's a great answer for a debian based system, but Buildroot isn't debian based.

Comment: @LovesTha Have a look at  *Old (first) answer*! This is less *Debian based*  and U could understand principle and implemant same mechanism for any kind of distribution/installation. (even if *Upgrading* section show Debian commands, U could do same for manual upgrading or any other distrib based upgrade.)

Comment: Your old answer would be a great answer to a generic question about setting up read only Linux systems. Once I've finished my exploration of making our buildroot's read only I hope to come back and give a great detailed answer on the specific question here.
Buildroot already has the temporary bits of /var symlinked to /tmp which is a tempfs. /etc shouldn't be used as a scratch space for programs, so it shouldn't need to be handled specially.

Comment: @LovesTha Care about *some files* in /etc, like /etc/resolv.conf (wich could be a simlink to a rw located file)

Comment: The way that file is used really feels like it should be in /var, but that is a completely different can of worms. And yes, buildroot by default makes that a symlink to /tmp/resolve.conf

Answer (score 4):

I only have experience using a more recent buildroot (2014-02). In that version you can disable 'remount root filesystem read-write duing boot' in the config file with:

BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_REMOUNT_ROOTFS_RW is not set

I managed to create an image that just uses its ext4 / partition as read only so unplugging the power of the system does not harm at all. It works great, so if you don't need to write to your filesystem, maybe this is a far simpler solution than the one mentioned above (which seems more or less applicable to a Debian system as it refers to apt-get).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - however in the end I opted for a initramfs setup with mounting just a couple of directories with sync option on the CF drive for data persistence. This has served me pretty well for the time being.

Comment: To add to this: using older buildroot versions, check `/etc/inittab` if remounting of `/` happens there. If so, change it to your needs.

Comment: This answer is an important piece of the 'buildroot way' to do it. Much of the advice in the accepted answer will be needed to make more complex systems work. Chances are though that all that will need to be done is set up a few extra symlinks to /tmp (tempfs) and everything works.