# Using ramfs on embedded system

Tags: embedded, initramfs

I am required to write some software to run on Linux installed on an x86 based embedded setup that has a 8GB compact flash drive for data storage. The critical requirements are logging measurement data to file every 30 seconds, and robustness to power loss (my system **MUST** be able to reboot successfully every time and logging data must not get corrupted). I have used buildroot to generate my kernel, crosstools and file system. Currently I have tried 2 things

1. Booting up using only the `.cpio` file system provided by buildroot.
2. Copying the file system to an `ext3` partition and telling syslinux that the root file system is located there.

If I use option 1. and have my root file system in RAM I will lose my data at power down. If I use option 2. then I run the risk of system files getting corrupted on power down. The answer to this question [Is using a read only root file system a good idea for embedded setup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60871/is-using-a-read-only-root-file-system-a-good-idea-for-embedded-setup) lead me to consider using a read only file system, but the only answer I have received is currently too advanced for my level of Linux expertise. This has lead me to consider using a RAM based file system. In the case of a RAM file system using the `.cpio` file to boot from, how could I possibly operate things so that I can ensure power down safety AND get persistent data storage for my data logging requirements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run your system off RAM (faster, read only, will come up in known good state, etc.)
2. Log your data to a separate partition on the USB stick.  Might try mounting it with `sync` if your writes are not too frequent.