# Why I cannot ssh on a read-only/machine?

Tags: ssh, readonly

First, I precise that I was able to ssh on this machine (I think an embedded system based on Debian 7), but I had to set `/` to read-only to prevent any power off problems. I verified that `/tmp`, `/var/log`, `/var/lock` are still writeable, but the `/home` folders where I'm not supposed to write anything in normal execution are read-only.

Anyway, an `ssh root@ip_address` fails with `ssh: connect to host ip_address port 22: Connection refused message`.

`ssh -v ...` tells:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.32.30" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.32.30 [192.168.32.30] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.32.30 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.32.30 port 22: Connection refused
```

Could you please tell me why and how to fix it?

EDIT: Here is how I set my FS to RO:

Original fstab file:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p2       /                    auto       defaults          1  1
proc                 /proc                proc       defaults              0  0
devpts               /dev/pts             devpts     mode=0620,gid=5       0  0
tmpfs                /run                 tmpfs      mode=0755,nodev,nosuid,strictatime 0  0
tmpfs                /var/volatile        tmpfs      defaults              0  0
/dev/mmcblk0p3       /data                auto       defaults,sync              0  1
```

Modified fstab file: (I only changed the first line)

```
/dev/mmcblk0p2       /                    auto       ro            1  1
proc                 /proc                proc       defaults              0  0
devpts               /dev/pts             devpts     mode=0620,gid=5       0  0
tmpfs                /run                 tmpfs      mode=0755,nodev,nosuid,strictatime 0  0
tmpfs                /var/volatile        tmpfs      defaults              0  0
/dev/mmcblk0p3       /data                auto       defaults,sync              0  1
```

EDIT 2:

I answered to someone that I can effectively access with ssh if the filesystem is rw.
This is not exactly true. If I boot with option ro in `fstab` and then remount `/` in rw, I cannot access with ssh. It works if I change option back to `default` and reboot.

Comment: Does it work again if you remove the read only restriction?

Comment: @bxm, just verified and yes but I've edited my post to give information about how I set the fs to ro. in case....

Comment: Have a look at [Is using a read only root file system a good idea for embedded setup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60998/27653) !!

Comment: Doesn’t look like /tmp is its own file system from your fstab, which as per EchoMike444 is not going to end well.

Comment: Can you log in without SSH (e.g. locally) and confirm that the SSH server runs and listens where it should?

Comment: 'If I boot with option ro in fstab and then remount / in rw, I cannot access with ssh. ' -- do you get logs from sshd then? What do they say?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski ilkkachu you are right. I didn't take care about that but dropbear is not started but in fact I don't see any error from dropbear in the message. Any way, echomike444 may be right /tmp is certainly not available when dropbear needs it.

Comment: @ilkkachu I finally found something: `mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/dropbear': Read-only file system`. I suppose I have to add it in fstab?

Comment: can you add the output `mount`

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so many thanks to everybody (EchoMike444, iLkkachu, Kamil Maciorowski) for pointing me to the right direction.

In fact I didn't precise that my `sshd` is `dropbear` and this one needs to write to `/var/lib` to start.

So I had to add this mount point to tmpfs to be able to connect to my target via ssh.

Answer (score 1):

ssh need to write into `/tmp` .

Your `/tmp/` is in a `/` mount .

if you run `df /tmp` it will display your `/`  mount point , and you can check that `df /run` is  a different mount point .

Comment: I don't think it could be the reason because both `/tmp`and `/run` are mounted as tmpfs in rw mode and in fact I can write in `/tmp` even if `/` is ro. but in I edited my post again because the problem may come from something else.

Comment: You may be right in fact as I can effectively write to /tmp once started up but I guess that tmpfs is started too late for dropbear. Is it possible?